# Selecting cypress elements that do not contain text with Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am working on a test which runs into a dropdown with invalid selections. The dropdown does not disable these, you can click them, they simply read "unavailable" for the product.

```
<select readonly="" class="size-selector">
  <option value="">Size</option>
  <option value="XS">XS</option>
  <option value="S">S - Unavailable</option>
  <option value="M">M - Unavailable</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
  <option value="XL">XL</option>
</select>
```

I want to be able to select the first option after `Size` which does not contain the text "Unavailable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this: You loop through the options fields in your drop down using `each()`. Now check for the inner text for each of the options using `text()` jquery method. Once you find the element, use `cy.select()` to select the element.

```
cy.get('select.size-selector option').each(($ele) => {
    if (!($ele.text().includes('Unavailable') || $ele.text().includes('Size'))) {
        cy.get('select.size-selector').select($ele.text())
        return false; // Needed to break each loops in Cypress
    }
})
```

Comment: This is over-complicated, please see below for simple Cypress commands to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

Cypress provides [.filter()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/filter) and the opposite [.not()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/not) to filter lists.

```
cy.get('option')
  .not(':contains("Unavailable")')      // exclude Unavailable
  .not(':contains("Size")')             // exclude list header
  //.not('[value=""]')                  // alternative way to exclude list header
  .eq(0)                                // take the first
  .invoke('text')                       // get the text
  .then(firstAvailableOption => {
    cy.get('select.size-selector')
      .select(firstAvailableOption)     // use text to select option
  })

cy.get('select.size-selector')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'XS')
```